# What exactly is a centripetal force when it is produced as a resultant of two or more forces?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Let's say we have an object on a ferris wheel undergoing uniform circular motion. It is known that the centripetal force(**f**) causing the circular motion is given by mv^2/r, where m is the mass of the object, v is its velocity and r its radius. But this force is a resultant of two forces that already act on the object, the normal contact force(**N**) between ferris wheel and the object, and the weight of the object(**W**). As a result, at the top  of the ferris wheel, the centripetal force is given by **f=W-N**. The textbooks I have been using then go on to rearrange the equation so that it is now **N=W-f**. They then use this equation to explain why if the speed of the object is greater than or equal to a certain value, the object will lose contact with the wheel. I do slightly understand this when I look at the equation from a mathematical point of view, but I wonder how practical it is. Since the centripetal force is a **RESULTANT FORCE** of the weight and normal contact force, what then does the equation **N=W-f** mean practically? Isn't a resultant force a simplification made in mechanics so that calculations and diagrams become easier to handle and conceptualize? If so what produces the the **f** force in **N=W-f**, unless some form of circular reasoning has been used, or  there is something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The centripetal force is itself a net force which must take a particular value in order to keep an object moving at a particular speed on a circular path of particular radius. That force can be caused by many different things - in the case of swinging a tennis ball on a string, string tension provides the centripetal force; in the case of the earth revolving around the sun, gravity provides the centripetal force; in the case of the Ferris wheel, some combination of gravity and mechanical stress provides the centripetal force. Centripetal force isn't really a "type" of force, it's just whatever force is keeping you on a circular trajectory, which could have any number of physical causes.

To maintain uniform circular motion, the centripetal force must have a constant magnitude and always point toward the center. At the top of the wheel, gravity provides some of the force pulling you toward the center of the wheel, so there is little mechanical stress needed. At the right speed, you'd become "weightless" at the top of the wheel, in which case you just "float" over the top of the wheel under the centripetal force of gravity alone. If you're moving slower than that, the wheel must hold you up, but if you're moving faster than that, the wheel must actually hold you *down* to prevent you flying off! The normal force in your equation is essentially what part of the centripetal force isn't accounted for by gravity and therefore must come from the mechanical stresses in the wheel itself.

Comment: "*To keep you moving in a circle, the centripetal force must have a constant magnitude...** Not necessarily. One can move along a circular path with a speed that changes, and thus with a changing centripetal force

Comment: @BioPhysicist Clarified that I'm referring to uniform circular motion there.

Comment: Cool! Although I am not sure if the OP specified uniform circular motion; I think the analysis point in question is just looking at the top of the circular trajectory (where the normal force would be at a minimum)

Comment: @BioPhysicist True, I don't think they're restricting to the uniform motion case, but I find it a bit easier conceptually to keep the centripetal force fixed and figure out what portion of it is coming from different sources at different points in the rotation.

Answer (score 2):

"Centripetal" is just a direction; so "centripetal force" it's not a force like weight, normal force, etc. Anything can be a "centripetal" force, just like anything can be a "vertical force".

In your equation, $f = W-N$, this is just saying telling us that the net centripetal force is equal to $W-N$. However, unlike the "vertical" example, when you are specifically looking at circular motion, then the net centripetal force has to also be equal to $mv^2/R$ in order to circular motion to occur. So, then, with a constant $W$, if we keep increasing the speed $v$, we see that $N$ needs to decrease in order to keep circular motion possible; and at some point one would need $N$ to change directions in order to keep the circular motion going. Since $N$ can't change directions here, we look for when $N=0$ to determine the speed at which circular motion can no longer occur.

$N=W-f$ can be interpreted as "this is what an additional applied force $N$ needs to be in order to maintain circular motion at speed $v$, where $f=mv^2/R$".